# fetch() with status code checking and re-routing

Tags: javascript, react.js, promise

In [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for `fetch()` I don't see many example for status code checking.

(1) I'm expecting to catch 403 unauthorised responses and push the login path to React router to render the login page. Haven't seen this elsewhere, but seems to work alright.

(2) Is it alright to nest the second `.then` the way I did or it should it somehow be outside the first `.then`?

```
loadData() {
    fetch(new UrlAssembler().template(this.props.endpoint).query(queryObject.get()).toString())
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                this.props.history.push( APP_LOGIN_PATH )
            } else {
                response.json().then(data =>
                    this.setState({
                        data: data,
                        loaded: true,
                        isModalActive: false,
                        selectedElement: null,
                        selectedId: null,
                    }))
                }
        })
}
```

Comment: Is a value expected to be returned from `loadData()` function call?

Comment: No there isn't. It's a React app, so it just changes the state.

Comment: If the code produces the correct result and does not expected a value to be returned from `loadData()` would only consider adding a `.catch()` to the chain, to handle errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see many example for status code checking

I think this way of thinking is a remnant of `jQuery.ajax` where anything not `2xx` rejects the promise. On the other hand, `fetch` makes a request, and returns an object that represents the response. It's up to you and your app to decide what's a "correct" response from a "wrong" response.

Coming from an Angular background, the task of capturing `403`s and doing redirects is the job of an HTTP interceptor service and not your component. This way, *your component is not aware of this logic* (it simply makes requests) and the behavior is applied globally on all your API calls. But since React doesn't have the same service structure, we'll make do with wrapping functions.

So ideally, what your component should only ever contain is:

```
someWrappedVersionOfFetch(...)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      data: data,
      loaded: true,
      isModalActive: false,
      selectedElement: null,
      selectedId: null,
    }))
  })
```

Then the wrapped fetch would be like:

```
export const someWrappedVersionOfFetch = (...args) => {
  return fetch(...args)
    .then(response => {

      if (response.status !== 200) {
        // Update your history and reject the promise
        history.pushState( APP_LOGIN_PATH )
        return Promise.reject(response)
      } else {
        // Just pass response through.
        return Promise.resolve(response)
      }
    })
}
```

The above answers your first question. For your second question, you could do it like the second snippet. You put the conditional on the first `then`, have it conditionally return a resolved or rejected promise. Then just chain the one with `setState` after it.

Comment: Where does OP explicitly return a rejected `Promise`? If a rejected `Promise` is introduced into the `Promise` chain should `.catch()` also be included to handle potential errors and prevent `Uncaught (in promise)` error where `.catch()` is not chained? Passing `response` to `Promise.resolve()` is not necessary, `.then()` returns a new `Promise` object. `else {
        // Just pass response through.
        return response
      }`, handle errors `.then(data => {..}).catch(err=>console.error(err))`

Comment: OK, I think I got it. So the component would use your `someWrappedVersionOfFetch` instead of `fetch` as I do. This way the component doesn't need to understand the status code checking, it just takes what it gets from `someWrappedVersionOfFetch` and does `setState` or if the promise is rejected, it does nothing. Status code checking can be applied globally by always using `someWrappedVersionOfFetch`

Comment: Is it appropriate to call `someWrappedVersionOfFetch` a middleware? So name it `fetchWithMiddleware` for example?

Comment: @M3RS Yes, "middleware" would be a good term to call it. They're usually transparent to the consumer.